# How to show animation on a image in android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am making an app in which people will upload a image and there will be two buttons to give like or dislike an image.

I want when any person click on a button a animation come on image showing percentage of total likes and dislikes.

Same an this image give below:-

[image]

Is there  a library to this if not can you please tell me how to do this.

I am saving number of likes and dislikes in firestore database. I can find percentage of them but I don't know how to show them a animation on a image.

Comment: Lottie is very usefull lib for animations here : https://medium.com/@eijaz/animations-in-android-using-lottie-kotlin-679364ed3f26

Comment: but lottie will only give animations,, I also want to set percentage to my animation